# Insert text field into pdf file using Python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, formatting, pdf-generation

I have a PDF file, which is essentially a picture of a ticket for an aerospace fair our universities space-technologies group is hosting. Users can enter their names on our Python-Flask based webpage and it should be pasted to the ticket-pdf at a certain location.

Unfortunately I've never done this before and what I find on the web looks pretty complicated and is overkill for what I am trying to accomplish.

I've already written the neccessary lines to create a copy of the original ticket for every user, now I only have to insert the name.

How would some example code look like for doing this with the pikepdf lib in Python 3.11?

(I've found python-aspose.word which looked pretty good for that, but there sadly isn't a version for Py3.11 so pikepdf suggested in an answer below is the only one I found working for this.)

Comment: There are many PDF toolsets for python. Google them, pick one, write some code. Then if you get stuck, ask for assistance. Recommendations are not appropriate for Stackoverflow.com

Comment: If I would have known which one to pick, I wouldn't have asked here. Apparently modifying PDF files is not as easy as it looks and you can mess it up very easily. None of the libs I found support text editing within PDFs.

Comment: And this is why SO can be SO frustrating, SO unhelpful, SO rigid-for-rigidity's-sake. Whatever happened to just helping people? If you know about "many PDF toolsets", then say something like "I've used this one to do what you're trying to do. Give it shot." At least, that's a +1 for the OP. Closing this question and responses like I've seen give SO a bad reputation: "I need help." "Here's an admonishment in response." "Great, thanks."

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty complicated problem as PDFs are kind of a nightmare to work with.  Reading the metadata and getting pages is pretty straight forward.  Modifying the existing data is really hard to not mess up.  Adding some additional text is moderately difficult, which is why a lot of PDF libraries don't support it.

If you just need to add some text at a specific location on a page, I think pikepdf can do that.  Below is a class that will open a PDF file, and enables adding text at a specific location, and makes the new file's bytes ready for export.

```
import pikepdf
from pathlib import Path
from io import BytesIO


class PdfTicketWriter:
    def __init__(self, blank_ticket_path: Path|str) -> None:
        # open the file and read in the first page
        self.blank_ticket_path = Path(blank_ticket_path)
        self.pdf_bytes = BytesIO(self.blank_ticket_path.read_bytes())
        self.pdf = None
        self.page = None
        self.instructions = None
        self.is_ready = True
        self.reload()

    def reload(self) -> None:
        """
        Reloads the pikepdf object from the PDF bytes.
        """
        self.pdf_bytes.seek(0)
        self.pdf = pikepdf.open(self.pdf_bytes)
        self.page = self.pdf.pages[0]
        self.instructions = pikepdf.parse_content_stream(self.page)
        self.add_courier

    def add_courier(self) -> None:
        """
        Adds a reference to the Courier font to the PDF.
        """
        if pikepdf.Name.Courier in self.page.resources.Font:
            return

        # add an indirect reference to one of the standard 11 fonts.
        courier = pikepdf.Dictionary(
            Type=pikepdf.Name.Font,
            Subtype=pikepdf.Name.Type1,
            BaseFont=pikepdf.Name.Courier,
            Name=pikepdf.Name.Courier,
        )

        self.pdf.make_indirect(courier)
        self.page.add_resource(courier, pikepdf.Name.Font, '/Courier')

    def make_text_instructions(self, 
                               text: str, 
                               x: float, 
                               y: float, 
                               size: float=9.0
                               ) -> list[pikepdf.ContentStreamInstruction]:
        """
        Creates list of low-level PDF instructions to add `text` at page 
        location `x`, `y`, with font size of `size`.
        """
        CSI = pikepdf.ContentStreamInstruction

        instructions = [
            CSI([], pikepdf.Operation('BT')),   # begin text
            CSI([pikepdf.Name.Courier, size], pikepdf.Operator('Tf')),  # set font
            CSI([1,0,0,1,x,y], pikepdf.Operator('Tm')),     # move cursor to x, y
            CSI([pikepdf.String(text)], pikepdf.Operator('Tj')),    # paint text
            CSI([], pikepdf.Operation('ET')),   # end text
        ]
        return instructions

    def insert_instructions(self, 
                            new_instructions: list[pikepdf.ContentStreamInstruction]
                            ) -> None:
        """
        Inserts the new set of instructions after the last ENDTEXT instruction.
        """
        ix = 0
        for i, (_, op) in enumerate(self.instructions):
            if str(op) == 'ET':
                ix = i
        self.instructions = [
            *self.instructions[:ix], 
            *new_instructions, 
            *self.instructions[ix:]
        ]
        # the pdf is not ready until the content stream is written
        self.is_ready = False

    def set_content_stream(self) -> None:
        """
        Sets the content stream of the page to the current set of instructions.
        """
        content_stream = pikepdf.unparse_content_stream(self.instructions)
        self.page.Contents = self.pdf.make_stream(content_stream)
        self.is_ready = True

    def add_text(self, text: str, x: float, y: float, size: float=9.0) -> None:
        """
        Adds the text at x, y and sets the content stream.
        """
        instr = self.make_text_instructions(text, x, y, size)
        self.insert_instructions(instr)
        self.set_content_stream()

    def to_bytesio(self) -> BytesIO:
        """
        Returns a BytesIO object of the modified PDF, if it is ready.
        """
        if not self.is_ready:
            raise BufferError('The content stream of the modified PDF has '
                'not been set, use `.set_content_stream`')
        
        fp_out = BytesIO()
        self.pdf.save(fp_out)
        fp_out.seek(0)
        return fp_out
```

To use it, you would instantiate it once, reference it in the Flask endpoint to add the text, and use the `to_bytesio` method to return a bytesIO object that can be passed back via Flask as a download.

```
ticket_writer = PdfTicketWriter('path/to/blank-ticket.pdf')

...

@app.route('/do_make_ticket', 'POST')
def make_ticket(name):
    # you will have to figure out x and y based on your ticket layout.
    x = 113.2
    y = 45.0

    ticket_writer.add_text(name)
    bytes_file = ticket_writer.to_bytesio()
    ticket_writer.reload()

    return send_file(
        bytes_file,
        mimetype='application/pdf',
        as_attachment=True,
        download_name=f'ticket-{name}.pdf'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll test this tomorrow, when I finally got enough sleep for once :D